# How can we prove that $e^{-jωn}$ converges at $0$ while n -> infinity?

Tags: summation, fourier-transform

I am trying to find the DTFT of a function.

Here is my problem:

[image]

How does he prove that $e^{(-jω)m+1} = 0$ ?

Comment: He is using that $$\left| \frac{e^{-j \omega}}{4}\right| = \frac{1}{4} < 1$$  In general, if $|z|<1$ then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}$.  This is the geometric sum formula.

Comment: Also note that $e^{-j \omega n}$ does not converge at 0 when $n\rightarrow\infty$, in fact it oscillates about the unit circle in the complex plane.  But this issue that you raise in the title does not have much to do with the sum problem you show in the question.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible,
cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: I was trying to take the limit of  $e^{−jωn}$ to prove that.

Comment: No, $e^{-j \omega n}$ has no limit.  But even if it did, the limit does not help since you must add up all the values in the sum.  For example, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(e^{-j\omega}/4)^n=0$, but the sum of these terms is not zero, the sum adds all the values.

Comment: Yes that was my confusion because I knew that that's a phasor. In general, do limits exist for imaginary numbers?

Comment: Perhaps you can examine your last comment if I mirror it back to you:  "In general, do limits exist for real numbers?"

Comment: Technically no because limits are an approximation.

Comment: I was pushing more towards "it depends, since the question itself is not clear."  For example the limit of the sequence of real numbers $\{-1,1,-1,1,-1,1...\}$ does not exist since we just get oscillation between 1 and -1, but the limit of the sequence of real numbers $\{1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, ...\}$ is certainly 0.

Comment: But isn't it still an approximation? For example, the limit of $x^2$ as x goes to infinity, is infinity but infinity is not a number. Anyways, I am not a mathematician so complex math is not for me! I am just trying to analyse some signals.

Comment: For a sequence of complex numbers $z_n = a_n + ib_n$, we say it converges to a complex number $z=a+ib$, so that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} z_n = z$, if $|z_n-z| = \sqrt{(a_n-a)^2 + (b_n-b)^2}\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Yup, this stuff is unknown to me. In ECE, we only learn about basic Laplace, Fourier and Z-Transforms and leave math there.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a formal answer to the question (it has already been answered in pieces in the above comments).

Let $z=a+bj$ be a complex number (where $a, b$ are real numbers and $j = \sqrt{-1}$).  The *magnitude* of $z$ is the distance between $(a,b)$ and $(0,0)$ in the 2-d plane: 
$$ |z| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$$

In general we have the *geometric sum formula* for a finite sum: 
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n}z^i = \frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z} $$
If $|z|<1$ then $|z|^n\rightarrow 0$.  So, taking a limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ gives the infinite sum formula in the special case when $|z|<1$:
$$ \boxed{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} z^i = \frac{1}{1-z} \quad , \quad \mbox{(if $|z|<1$)}} $$
In your summation you have (assuming $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$): 
$$ z = \frac{e^{-j\omega}}{4} = \frac{cos(\omega) - j\sin(\omega)}{4} $$
$$ \implies |z| = \frac{1}{4} < 1 $$
so the infinite sum formula (in the above box) can be applied.